# Error in my List' Initializer 'init(_:id:rowContent:)' requires that 'ShopsModel' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"

Tags: swiftui-list, identifiable

I have a struct for ShopsModel that complies to Identifiable.

```
struct ShopsModel: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var shopName: String
    var postcode: String
    var type: String
}
```

I have two shops (there will be more!):

```
let shop1 = ShopsModel(
    id: 1,
    shopName: "shop1",
    postcode: "PE31 8AA",
    type: "Clothing")

let shop2 = ShopsModel(
    id: 2,
    shopName: "shop2",
    postcode: "PE31 8AB",
    type: "Clothing")

And my list code
```

import SwiftUI

struct ShopsList2: View {

```
let shops2: ShopsModel

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationStack {
        List(shops2, id: \.self.id) { shop in
            NavigationLink {
                ShopsDetail(name: shop)
            } label: {
                Text(shop)
            }
    }.navigationTitle("Shops")
}
```

}

```
then the error: Initializer 'init(_:id:rowContent:)' requires that 'ShopsModel' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I added an id to each instance of ShopsModel and I made the struct identifiable.  I thought that would get rid of the error.  It didn't
I also have an error on preview and I can't work out what to put in the parentheses as it doesn't seem to recognise shops2.

Comment: that is a single model, you need an array for a `List`. You should look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials

Comment: I thought I was making an array by having multiple instances of ShopModel.

Comment: The instances have to be together in an array/RandomAccessCollection. There is no connection in between them right now.

Comment: How do I do that? Do I just string them together between square brackets? What separator do I use between the instances?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/collectiontypes/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/